# nothing change aftercheckout commit

Tags: git

I used this command:

```
git checkout dc8a2c845c615598b2be6a3a0f109f18c44dd836
```

to go back to the last commit  and temporaly discard the changes after the commit,but the changes are still there,do I missed somenthing?

Comment: Are these changes ("after the commit") uncommited? If yes, you're looking for `git stash`.

Comment: Also, please add the output of your command to your answer.

Comment: @kowsky yes this changes are uncommited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What you want to use instead of `git checkout`:

If you have some uncommited changes, you can "stash" them temporarily using `git stash` ([Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)). To retrieve them, use `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`. The first one will apply the changes and keep them stashed, allowing you to apply them again, while the latter will apply them and remove them from the stash stack. In both cases, your changes will be back as unstaged changes.

If you would use `git reset --hard`, your changes would be lost, so be careful with that.

EDIT:

### Why `git checkout` did not do what you thought it would:

`git checkout dc8a2c845c615598b2be6a3a0f109f18c44dd836` will checkout the given commit, i.e. move the HEAD pointer of your current branch to that commit. Alas, since the changes you made on top of your branch are not yet commited, your branches HEAD *already* points to that commit! So, the command changes nothing, since your unstaged changes are not affected by changing the branches HEAD pointer.

More detailed: git knows three trees: The working directory, the Index and HEAD. See [this article about git reset](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified) for further explanation on that. Now, according ti [its' documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_description), `git checkout` will

> To prepare for working on *branch*, switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing HEAD at the branch. **Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept**

So, as stated above, the files in the index and the working tree will be updated to the state in the provided commit, the branches HEAD will point to the commit, but local changes (exactly those you wanted to get rid of) are kept!